# I want to make a profile progress bar if the user fill their profile data then progress bar must be fill with colour

Tags: react-native

Here is the example of progress bar
[image: On top is progress bar i have completed 90% of my profile]

Answer (score 0):

you can use **react-native-progress** package to develop as same progressbar as you mentioned in your image.

to change color

1. color (active color)
2. unfilledColor (inActive color)